# My app using web server inorder to save and load data to the database how can i save the form without click the submit button?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, html, objective-c

I have a iphone application when the user presses the button i collect data and send it to web server that is written by php.I made a form there and of course my form has a submit button but when the user press the button in the application how can i tell the form to submit the text that user choses. here is my php code

```
<?php require_once('Connections/local.php')?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['appy_level'])){
$id=mysql_insert_id();

$appy_level=$_POST['appy_level'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$date =date('Y');
$year=$date-$year;
$reasons = $_POST['reasons'];
$reasons = str_replace(","," ",$reasons); 
if(isset($_POST['sex']))
 $sex=$_POST['sex'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$id=mysql_insert_id();

$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO user (age,wname,slid,time,sex) VALUES                 (".$year.",".$reasons.",".$appy_level.",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,".$sex.")";
 $insertSQL1="INSERT INTO country (c_name) VALUES (".$country.")";
 $insertSQL2="INSERT INTO city (ci_name) VALUES (".$city.")";
mysql_select_db($database_local, $local);
mysql_query($insertSQL, $local) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($insertSQL1, $local) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($insertSQL2, $local) or die(mysql_error());

}
?>


  <body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
 <table>
<tr>
<td>Happyness level:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="appy_level" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reasons:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="reasons" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="sex" value=""  maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="country" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="city" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Year:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="year" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td> </td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>        
</body>
```

How can i submit my form without a submit button. when the user presses the button ok in iphone application i want to submit his information to database.

Comment: `$year=$_POST['year'];`  Where is your form field for 'year'?

Comment: you can see now mate sorry i forgot to post the all form

Comment: You are trying to save as the user types, so you can reload it later?  Or what?

Comment: yes i am going to retrive them from database when the user clicks show button in the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see where you are connecting to your database, the connection you are trying to use is `$local`, here:

```
mysql_query($insertSQL, $local) or die(mysql_error());
```

If the values you are trying to insert are strings, you need to enclose them in single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(col1, col2, col3, ..., colN) VALUES('val1', 'val2', 'val3', ..., 'valN')
```

You should wrap the string values in quotes and not forget to protect against sql injection by escaping the strings:

```
$val1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['val1']);
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName(val1) VALUES('" . $val1 . "')";
mysql_query($query, $local);
```